# How to call a Sinatra route from IRB console

Tags: ruby, sinatra, irb

I loaded my app into IRB console by typing **irb** into bash then in the console using:

```
require 'myapp.rb'
```

It all worked successfully, now I want to call one of my routes.

```
get '/stuff' do
  '<HTML><BODY><CENTER>App is up and running! '\
  'Less logging...</CENTER></BODY></HTML>'
end
```

How can I use IRB console to test this route?

Comment: IRB is the standard ruby console.  Sorry for the case differences. It's fixed now. I basically did "irb" in my bash command line then require "myapp.rb".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I discovered the Tux gem.  It allows calling of get and post routes from within IRB console.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class MySinatraApp < Sinatra::Base
    get "/test_endpoint/"
        "Hello world"
    end
    # ...
end

require "rack/test"
def app
  MySinatraApp
end

Rack::Test::Methods.get("/test_endpoint/")
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for testing? If so, you should try a test framework.

But it is possible to do so in irb:
[Link](http://www.sinatrarb.com/testing.html)

And go to "Using Rack::Test without the Mixin"

```
> require_relative 'myapp'
> require 'rack/test'
> browser = Rack::Test::Session.new(Rack::MockSession.new(Sinatra::Application))
> browser.get '/stuff'
> browser.last_response.body
```